# Dropdown menu doesn't work in html and css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2022

Hi I want to hide the dropdown-menu submenu but it seems doesn't work. I use the property `display: block !important;` and it doesn't hide it and when I try `display: none !important;` and doesn't dropdown as well.

What I want is when I touched it then it will hover down the dropdown submenu then only showed.
Where does it causes the submenu couldn't work and I need the solution for this?
I need help with this.

Thank You.

Here is the result after I executed:
[image: Output of Failed Design Dropdown]

Here is my expect output that need to be showed
[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg0j3.png)

```css
nav li {
  /* remove all the bullets and baked in style - probably should use div set instead */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-link {
  color: #000080;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.navbar-head {
  background-color: #000099;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-head2 {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-brand>strong {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* Divider line */

.menu-hr-line {
  /* border-top-width: 3px;*/
  border-top-color: #000099;
}


/* Dropdown menu */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #777;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-header {
  color: #050A30;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu .columns-4 {
  min-width: 1300px;
  background-color: #e6ffff;
}

.dropdown .has-megamenu {
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu .submenu {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.dropdown-menu>li:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown>li>a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.324624;
  color: #000c66;
  white-space: normal;
}

.multi-column-dropdown>li>a:hover {
  color: cornflowerblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar-head">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" title="facility portal">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>PORTAL</strong></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="navbar-head2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="~/Home" class="navbar-link">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">GENERAL <span class="caret"></span></span>
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a id="A1" href="#">Chart</a></li>
              <li><a id="A2" href="#">Document</a></li>
              <li><a id="A3" href="#">Equipment</a></li>
              <li><a id="A4" href="#">Utility</a></li>
              <li><a id="A5" href="#">Plant</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu"><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">MODULES <span class="caret"></span></span>
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4">
              <li>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Report</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="border-top-3 solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown"><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="data-toggle">Daily <span class="caret"></span></span>
                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu submenu">
                          <li><a id="A16" href="#">1</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A17" href="#">3</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A18" href="#">5</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A19" href="#">7</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A20" href="#">9</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A21" href="#">12</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A7" href="#">Weekly</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A8" href="#">Abnormality</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A9" href="#">Plant</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A10" href="#">Calibration</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A11" href="#">Supervising</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Inventory</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A12" href="#">Items</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Schedule</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A13" href="#">Master</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Documentation</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A14" href="#">Equipment</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A15" href="#">Drawing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">OFFINE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You marked this as bootstrap-5 so I added that to your snippet but it does not appear to reproduce the same UI as your picture

Comment: Hi @MarkSchultheiss. I have changed the bootstrap-5 to bootstrap-4. I used Visual Studio 2022 and the bootstrap for the website I used is Bootstrap v3.4.1 (getbootstrap.com). From my code, I need to do more enhance so that I could match with the same UI as the image I send. But for the UI part, I need help from you because I am poor in css for this. Could Mark help me on the part for this css? Thanks a lot, Mark.

Comment: I edited (you could have done that) for the bootstrap 4 instead.  Most often with CSS people have TOO MUCH and start tying to fix with MORE which is NOT the way to go in many cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkSchultheiss. I have compiled the code that you have provided. The output for the mega menu dropdown couldn't work as the image that I posted exactly. After I executed, the output become all fit into one. The css part there I have try everything that I can but it stills the same. Could you help me on this? And, the navbar-header2 for GENERAL and MODULES, I don't know why they stick together because it should be showed like the image I posted. 

Image posted after I executed.

Thanks a lot, Mark.

Comment: Given the relative effort to match with your desired output compared to a "standard" navigation bar you are not likely to get a great answer here - it is a non-trivial effort to answer as it stands with basically multiple questions disguised as one here - like how to get the "second" level navigation as a full bar that includes sub-menus etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution here - too much to do here to make it a "full" answer.  Note for this I removed a lot of the `runat="server"` since it was out of scope of the question.  You also have to work out the challenges with the "links as dropdown triggers" here.  FWIW I would ditch all the nested UL/LI and just use a set of nested divs' with proper classes for the bootstrap instead. I don't have more time at present to fully vet this out and fix it all.  NOTE: I have commented out a good majority of the CSS here since it really feels like "too much" - especially when combined with Bootstrap which can do a lot of it with classes.

```css
nav li {
  /* remove all the bullets and baked in style - probably should use div set instead */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-link {
  color: #000080;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.navbar-head {
  background-color: #000099;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.menu-hr-line {
  /* border-top-width: 3px;*/
  border-top-color: #000099;
}


/*
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #777;
  border-color: #fff;
}


.navbar-head2 {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.dropdown.has-megamenu {
  position: static;
}
*
.dropdown-header {
  color: #050A30;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu.columns-4 {
  min-width: 1345px;
  background-color: #e6ffff;
}
.dropdown-menu .submenu {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu>li:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.324624;
  color: #000C66;
  white-space: normal;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar-head">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" title="portal">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>PORTAL</strong></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="navbar-head2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="~/Home" class="navbar-link">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <!-- <a runat="server" href="~/General" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">GENERAL<span class="caret"></span></a> --><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">GENERAL<span class="caret"></span></span>
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a id="A1" href="#">Chart</a></li>
              <li><a id="A2" href="#">Document</a></li>
              <li><a id="A3" href="#">Equipment</a></li>
              <li><a id="A4" href="#">Layout</a></li>
              <li><a id="A5" href="#">Plant</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
            <!-- <a runat="server" href="~/Modules" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">MODULES <span class="caret"></span></a> -->
            <span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">MODULES <span class="caret"></span></span>
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4">
              <li>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Report</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="border-top-3 solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span>Daily</span>
                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu submenu">
                          <li><a id="A16" href="#">1</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A17" href="#">3</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A18" href="#">5</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A19" href="#">7</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A20" href="#">9</a></li>
                          <li><a id="A21" href="#">12</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A7" href="#">Weekly</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A8" href="#">Abnormality</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A9" href="#">Plant</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A10" href="#">Calibration</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A11" href="#" r>Supervising</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Inventory</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A12" href="#">Items</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Schedule</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A13" href="#">Master</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Documentation</li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" />
                      </li>
                      <li><a id="A14" href="#"> Equipment</a></li>
                      <li><a id="A15" href="#">Drawing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">OFFICE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper HTML element is `<select>`.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  document.getElementById("select").toggleAttribute("disabled");
});
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  document.getElementById("select").toggleAttribute("hidden");
});
```

```html
<label for="select">Choose a pet:</label>

<select name="pets" id="select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button id=button>Enable/Disable Select Element</button>
<button id=button2>Show/Hide Select Element</button>
```

Comment: Alas the lack of ability to style `<select>` and  `<input type="date"` lead to a great number of workarounds as you probably know already.  However `ul/li` are not IMHO a great choice for this either due to built-in style for those.